How to convert string into Expression or a different dynamic filter expression I can use in a R SQL Pull?
I have a list of columns that I need to scan in a SQL database to see if each column contains an ICD-10 code stored in a list variable called first_three_chars.
 #List of columns to scan
 list <- c('D1','D2','D3','D4','D5','D6','D7','D8','D9','D10','D11','D12','D13')

I have successfully done this manually with the following code. Note:  claims_tbl is a tibble (temporary data set of a large database table).
  claim_dplyr_tbl <- claims_tbl %>%
    filter(
          ((substr(D1, 1, 3) %in% first_three_chars) | 
           (substr(D2, 1, 3) %in% first_three_chars) | 
           (substr(D3, 1, 3) %in% first_three_chars) |
           (substr(D4, 1, 3) %in% first_three_chars) | 
           (substr(D5, 1, 3) %in% first_three_chars) |
           (substr(D6, 1, 3) %in% first_three_chars) | 
           (substr(D7, 1, 3) %in% first_three_chars) | 
           (substr(D8, 1, 3) %in% first_three_chars) | 
           (substr(D9, 1, 3) %in% first_three_chars) |
           (substr(D10, 1, 3) %in% first_three_chars) | 
           (substr(D11, 1, 3) %in% first_three_chars) |   
           (substr(D12, 1, 3) %in% first_three_chars) | 
           (substr(D13, 1, 3) %in% first_three_chars))) %>%
    collect()

However, I need to make this dynamic because I have multiple data sets and the list above will change the number of columns and column names. Thus, I'm trying to construct the filter statement dynamically but am having trouble doing so.
I've tried the following in which I try to create a string and then use that string as an expression. But, despite the string being the same as above, whenever I run it I get an error of incorrect syntax near first_three_chars. Does anyone know how to convert this string into a form I can use in the filter statement?
  # Construct the filter command
  filter_conditions <- sapply(list, function(col) {
    paste0("(substr(", col, ", 1, 3) %in% first_three_chars)")
  })
  # Join the conditions with `|`
  final_command <- paste(filter_conditions, collapse = " | ")
  # Ensure the final command is properly formatted
  print(final_command)
  # Construct the filter expression
  filter_expr <- str2lang(final_command)

  claim_dplyr_tbl2 <- claims_tbl %>%
             (filter_expr)) %>%
    collect()


Just as a follow-up to my previous comment on my answer, this link has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular.

This solution works independently of column names and returns all columns that contain values that start with the three-character strings in the first_three_chars vector.
It works by converting first_three_chars to a regular expression e.g. c("ABC", "DEF") becomes ^(ABC|DEF) where "^" denotes searching from the start of the strings.
I changed the order of filter() and select(). If select() was first, columns containing matching strings that are outside the date range would be retained.
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

# Create date filter strings
start_date <- "2024-08-24"
end_date <- "2024-08-30"

# Create vector of three letter strings to search for
first_three_chars <- c("ABC", "DEF")

# Create example df
claim_dplyr_tbl <- 
  data.frame(
    date1 = as.character(seq(as.Date("2024-08-22"), by = "day", length.out = 10)),
    A1 = c("ABC1", rep("", 9)),
    B1 = c(rep("", 4), "ABC1", rep("", 5)),
    C1 = c(c(rep("", 9), "DEF1")),
    D1 = c(rep("", 6), "DEF2", rep("", 3)),
    E1 = c(rep("", 2), "ABC2", rep("", 7)),
    F1 = c(rep("", 3), "GHI3", rep("", 6)))

# Convet date1 to as.Date(), filter df by dates, select columns containing strings
# that start with first_three_chars values
result <- claim_dplyr_tbl |>
  mutate(start_claim = as.Date(date1)) |>
  filter((start_claim >= as.Date(start_date)) & 
           (start_claim <= as.Date(end_date))) |>
  select(start_claim,
         where(~ any(str_detect(., paste0("^(", paste(first_three_chars, collapse = "|"), ")")))))

result
#   start_claim   B1   D1   E1
# 1  2024-08-24           ABC2
# 2  2024-08-25               
# 3  2024-08-26 ABC1          
# 4  2024-08-27               
# 5  2024-08-28      DEF2     
# 6  2024-08-29               
# 7  2024-08-30                     


I appreciate the solution but it won't work in the situation. Two things I should clarify. One claim_dplyr_tbl is a tibble, not a data frame. It's a temporary data set pulled from a database of hundreds of millions of rows. The reason I had the original structure was because I have to consider runtime as well. I can add a step where I subset the original data to just the columns I need to remove the select statement. However, the where statement didn't work with the tibble.

@Health_Code13 - yes, I assumed that. Given you did not provide the full context of your workflow, I skipped the subset. You will need to update your question so it is a minimal, reproducible example. Any sample data that you include does not need to be millions of rows, or contain confidential data. You can just create a toy dataset to represent claims_tbl. Your toy dataset will need to reproduce the issue with where() that you described.

I changed it to only include the filter statement but the current solution won't work and will produce the following error  This tidyselect interface doesn't support predicates.
